# What's the appropriate way to take pandas groupby results with no function and combine them into columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I'm grouping by index, in this case `Household_0`. I would like to combine all of the grouped data into a series and lay them out as Individuals.

Sample data:

```
data = {'Household_0':['2374550','2374550','2374553', 
                       '2374554','2374554',
                       '2374555','2374555'],
        'Individual_0':['2374548','2374548','','',
                        '4444444','2379908','2379909'],
        'Individual_1':['2374549','','','','','2379910','']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index('Household_0',inplace=True)
```

Which results in:

```
            Individual_0 Individual_1
Household_0                          
2374550          2374548      2374549
2374550          2374548             
2374553                              
2374554                              
2374554          4444444             
2374555          2379908      2379910
2374555          2379909
```

I want to group `Household_0` and have only one entry for each Household, which includes all of the values for Individuals, and removes duplicates.

The resultant dataframe would look like:

```
Household_0     Individual_0   Individual_1  Individual_2
2374550         2374548        2374549
2374553 
2374554         4444444
2374555         2379908        2379909       2379910
```

Note that I already have fields up to Individual_9 in my existing dataframe. The appended digit has no significance, so ideally I'd just collapse all of the results down to the first Individual column that's free. And I'd also prefer to have them sorted from lowest to highest, but I can surely figure that one out on my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step `stacks` all the households, ignores the empty strings and removes the duplicates. Sorting gives your preferred order.

```
df1 = (df.stack().loc[lambda x: x!='']
         .reset_index() 
         .drop(columns='level_1')
         .drop_duplicates()
         .sort_values(0))

#  Household_0        0
#0     2374550  2374548
#1     2374550  2374549
#4     2374555  2379908
#6     2374555  2379909
#5     2374555  2379910
#3     2374554  4444444
```

Now this is a `pivot` problem. We'll use a `groupby` + `cumcount` to create the column indicator for the pivot. Finally, we'll need to `reindex` to include Household's that have nobody. Also some housekeeping on the column names.

```
df1['col_num'] = df1.groupby('Household_0').cumcount()
(df1.pivot(index='Household_0', columns='col_num', values=0)
    .add_prefix('Individual_')
    .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
    .reindex(df.index.unique()))
```

---

```
            Individual_0 Individual_1 Individual_2
Household_0                                       
2374550          2374548      2374549          NaN
2374553              NaN          NaN          NaN
2374554          4444444          NaN          NaN
2374555          2379908      2379909      2379910
```

---

I don't suggest this method because of the slow `.apply(pd.Series)` which will lead to a big performance hit, but this is possible by getting the uniques within group and then applying `pd.Series`. Much less code, at the cost of being inefficient.

```
(df.replace('', np.NaN).stack()
   .groupby(level=0).unique().apply(pd.Series)
   .add_prefix('Individual_')
   .reindex(df.index.unique()))
```

Comment: This works on the sample data I created, as you show. I'm having some trouble on my working data but I think you've done a good enough job explaining yourself that I can back into my issue. I will mark as accepted once I am able to confirm. Thank you for laying it out so well.

Comment: Specifically what's happening is that Household_0 isn't represented anymore after the pivot, and the created Individuals are all NaN. Prior to the pivot, the stack looks correct as does the column indicator. I'm still digging. I definitely tried to make an example that was representative of some of the data challenges.

Comment: @markf I did all the manipulations on a new object `df1` because at the very end I need the original `df.index` in: `.reindex(df.index.unique())`; this is **not** df1's index. Perhaps you're incorrectly reindexing on `df1`'s index? The other thing could be that you kept everything named `df`, instead of creating a separate object. That's perfectly fine, but before even the stacking step do something like `households = df.index.unique()` then do all the manipulations and in the end you can `.reindex(households)`

Comment: You found it. I was able to get a partial result removing that reindex, so I knew it had something to with it. I just visually missed the df/df1 difference, since my working frame is named differently. Thanks for the patience and help. Our nonprofit appreciates it..